# How to find the quotient set for $x^2-xy+2x-2y=0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am really confused as this equality only works when x=y

Comment: Do you know what is the [quotient set](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Quotient_Set) ?

Comment: From my understanding it's the set of all equivalence classes on a set.

Comment: Correct: the set of all equivalence classes defined by an equiv relation. Thus, you have to identify the relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
$$x^2-xy+2x-2y=(x-y)(x+2)$$